# group by properties and sum of values between nested json and array of objects

Tags: group-by, sum, lodash

I have users array with their name,

```
var users = [{'name':'zulekha'}, {'name':'deepika'}];
```

I am fetching worklogged by each user from jira APIs. So I am getting object like this.

```
var worklogResult = {
  "issues": [
    {
      "fields": {
        "worklog": {
          "worklogs": [
            {
              "author": {
                "name": "zulekha",
              },
              "timeSpentSeconds": 180
            },
            {
              "author": {
                "name": "deepika",
              },
              "timeSpentSeconds": 210
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "fields": {
        "worklog": {
          "worklogs": [
            {
              "author": {
                "name": "deepika",
              },
              "timeSpentSeconds": 140
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "fields": {
        "worklog": {
          "worklogs": [
            {
              "author": {
                "name": "zulekha",
              },
              "timeSpentSeconds": 600,
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "fields": {
        "worklog": {
          "worklogs": []
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to match **worklogResult** with **users** in such a way that I can get following output.

output = [{'name':'zulekha','timeSpentSeconds':780}, {'name':'deepika', 'timeSpentSeconds':350}]

Can anyone suggest me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `_.flatMap` to flat nested objects

```
_.chain(worklogResult.issues)
    .flatMap('fields.worklog.worklogs')
    .thru(function(spents) {
        return _.map(users, function(user) {
            return _.merge(user, {
                timeSpentSeconds: _.chain(spents)
                    .filter(['author.name', user.name])
                    .map('timeSpentSeconds')
                    .sum()
                    .value()
            })
        })
    })
    .value()
```

Comment: Thanks. It helps :)